# Trace Propagate in Google Cloud with Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, trace, open-telemetry

I need to be able to propagate the trace from a publisher to a subscriber via pub sub without including anything in the message. That is, it must be able to propagate without inserting anything into the message. Only in the headers.
I tried with all the possible ways, but I have not been able to get both to appear in the same trace:
https://google-cloud-opentelemetry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/cloud_trace_propagator/README.html

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-python/tree/main/opentelemetry-propagator-gcp

I greatly appreciate any contribution.
Many thanks!

First way:

```
set_global_textmap(CloudTraceFormatPropagator())
```

---

Second way:

```
data = get_json()
trace_id_str = data['traceid']
carrier = {'traceparent': trace_id_str}

ctx = TraceContextTextMapPropagator().extract(carrier=carrier)
with tracer.start_as_current_span("/api/doit", ctx) as span:
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself recently, and I while I don't think it's possible natively with the Google Python PubSub SDK (at time of writing), you probably have to instrument it yourself. What I thought of was trying to add an attribute to the PubSub message if you don't want to alter the actual message body.

You can add a custom attribute which sits in the message metadata, which you could use in your downstream application.

```py
publisher_client.publish(topic=MY_TOPIC, data=MESSAGE_BODY, traceId=trace_id)
```